# QBO3 Summary statement missing foreign key details

Tags: configuration, qbo3

I have created a new QBO3 module, `MySubject`, including foreign keys to the Organization table for `InvestorID` and `ServicerID`.

When I call `MySubject\Summary`, I don't see the Organization records for the investor or servicer.

However, calling QBO3's core `Loan\Summary` does produce such foreign key output:

```
<LoanCollection>
  <LoanItem>...</LoanItem>
  <OrganizationItem>{Investor info is here}</OrganizationItem>
  <OrganizationItem>{Servicer info is here}</OrganizationItem>
  ...
</LoanCollection>
```

What do I need to do to ensure the `Organization` nodes are emitted in the `MySubject\Summary` output?

Answer (score 0):

Add the names of your foreign key columns to a `ForeignKeys` parameter of your `MySubject\Summary` statement.

Out of the box, the `Loan\Summary` statement includes:

> [image]

`ForeignKeys = " ServicerID AgencyID InvestorID AssignedOrganizationID AssignedPersonID "`

Note the preceding and trailing spaces on this value!

A [copy of the documentation](http://blog.quandis.com/quandis-business-objects-3/qbo-application/summary-and-summaryflat-methods) is below.

---

It is possible for the Summary statement to return too much information. By default, all ancestors and children are included in Summary results. If an object has hundreds or thousands of children, and those children are rarely needed in the Summary statement, they can be excluded. To tailor summary results, create a Summary Statement from Design > Configuration > Installed Modules > {Module} > Statements, and add one or more of the following parameters:

- AncestorDepth (int): determines how many generations of ancestors
  will be returned. Enter 0 to return no ancestors, 1 to return the
  immediate parent, etc.
- DescendantDepth (int): determines how many generations of descendants
  will be returned. Enter 0 for no descendants, 1 for children, 2 for
  grandchildren, etc.
- Ancestors (string):  a space-delimited string of ancestors to be
  included (if NULL, all ancestors will be included)
- Descendants (string): a space-delimited string of descendants to be
  included (if NULL, all descendants will be included)
- ForeignKeys (string): a space-delimited string of foreign key columns
  to include in the output (if NULL, no foreign keys will be included)
- MaxCount (int): determines the maximum number of child records of a
  given table and generation to include